# Prove the limit problem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

**Problem**

Assume $f(x)\in C^1[a,b]$. For any partion $P$ of $[a,b]$,
$$P:x_0=a<x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_n=b,$$
define $$\lambda_P=\max\{\Delta x_k=x_k-x_{k-1}| k=1,2,\cdots,n\}$$ and $$\varepsilon_P=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{f(x_{k-1})+f(x_k)}{2}\Delta x_k-\int_a^b f(x){\rm d}x.$$
Prove $$\lim_{\lambda_P \to 0}\frac{\varepsilon_P}{\lambda_P}=0.$$

**Attempt**

This is a problem involving the error of the **trapezoid method for the integral**. Let $M$ be a upper bound of $|f'(x)|$ over $[a,b]$. Then

\begin{align*} |\varepsilon_P|&=\left|\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{f(x_{k-1})+f(x_{k})}{2}\Delta x_k-\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{x_{k-1}}^{x_k} f(t){\rm d}t\right|\\ &\le\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n \left|f(x_{k-1})+f(x_k)-2f(\xi_k)\right|\Delta x_k\\ &\le \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(|f(x_{k-1})-f(\xi_k)|+|f(x_k)-f(\xi_k)|\right)\Delta_{x_k}\\ &\le M\sum_{k=1}^n\Delta_{x_k}^2\\ &\le M\lambda_P(b-a). \end{align*}

But this only supports the fact that $\frac{\varepsilon_P}{\lambda_P}$ is bounded. How to make it more precise?

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\quad\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{f(x_{k-1})+f(x_k)}{2}\Delta x_k-\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\mathrm{~d}x\\&=\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{x_{k-1}}^{x_k}\frac{f(x_{k-1})+f(x_k)}{2}\mathrm{~d}x-\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{x_{k-1}}^{x_k}f(x)\mathrm{~d}x\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{x_{k-1}}^{x_k}\left(\frac{f(x_{k-1})+f(x_k)}{2}-f(x)\right)\mathrm{~d}x\\&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{x_{k-1}}^{x_k}[\left(f(x_{k-1})-f(x)\right)+(f(x_k)-f(x))]\mathrm{~d}x\\&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{x_{k-1}}^{x_k}\left[\int_{x}^{x_{k-1}}f'(t)\mathrm{~d}t+\int_{x}^{x_{k}}f'(t)\mathrm{~d}t\right]\mathrm{d}x\\&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{x_{k-1}}^{x_k}\left[\int_{x_k}^{t}f'(t)\mathrm{~d}x+\int_{x_{k-1}}^{t}f'(t)\mathrm{~d}x\right]\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{x_{k-1}}^{x_k}f'(t)[2t-(x_k+x_{k-1})]\mathrm{~d}t.
\end{aligned}
$$
Since for $k=1,2,\cdots,n$, there are
$$\int_{x_{k-1}}^{x_k}[2t-(x_k+x_{k-1})]\mathrm{~d}t=0.$$
We have
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\quad\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{f(x_{k-1})+f(x_k)}{2}\Delta x_k-\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\mathrm{~d}x\\&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{x_{k-1}}^{x_k}(f'(t)-f'(x_{k-1}))[2t-(x_k+x_{k-1})]\mathrm{~d}t\\&\leq\sum_{k=1}^n w^{f'}_k\int_{x_{k-1}}^{x_k}\left|t-\frac{x_k+x_{k-1}}{2}\right|\mathrm{~d}t\\&\leq
\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=1}^n w^{f'}_k\Delta x_k^2\\
&\leq \frac{1}{4}\lambda_P\sum_{k=1}^n w^{f'}_k\Delta x_k\leq \frac{1}{4}\lambda_P\,\varepsilon,
\end{aligned}
$$
where
$w^{f'}_k=\sup_{[x_{k-1}\,\,,\,x_k\,]}f'-\inf_{[x_{k-1}\,\,,\,x_k\,]}f'.$ In the last inequality, we used the fact that if $f'$ is integrable, then $\forall\,\varepsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for any partition $P$ with $\lambda_P<\delta$, there is
$$\sum_{k=1}^n w^{f'}_k\Delta x_k<\varepsilon.$$

Answer (score 0):

Someone has posted a proof [here](https://www.zhihu.com/question/610059181/answer/3103715566):

Applying the MVT for integration and differeniation, we have

\begin{align*}  0\le\left|\frac{\varepsilon_P}{\lambda_P}\right|&=\frac{1}{\lambda_P}\left|\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{f(x_{k-1})+f(x_{k})}{2}\Delta x_k-\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{x_{k-1}}^{x_k} f(t){\rm d}t\right|\\[5pt] &\le\frac{1}{2\lambda_P}\sum_{k=1}^n \left|f(x_{k-1})+f(x_k)-2f(\xi_k)\right|\Delta x_k ~~~\color{blue}{(x_{k-1}<\xi_k<x_k)}\\[5pt]  &= \frac{1}{2\lambda_P}\sum_{k=1}^n|(f(x_{k})-f(\xi_k))-(f(\xi_k)-f(x_{k-1}))|\Delta{x_k}\\[5pt]  &\le \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n|f'(\eta_k)-f'(\mu_k)|\Delta{x_k}~~~\color{blue}{(x_{k-1}<\mu_k<\xi_k<\eta_k<x_k)}\\[5pt] &\le  \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n \omega_k'\Delta{x_k},  \end{align*}
where $\omega'_k$ denotes the amplitude of $f'$ over $[x_{k-1},x_k]$. Since $f'\in C^1[a,b]%$ , it is integrable. Therefore, by Darboux's theorem, which gives a necessary and sufficient condition for the integrablity of a function, $\displaystyle\lim\limits_{\lambda_P\to 0}\sum_{k=1}^n\omega'_k\Delta x_k=0.$ Eventually, the conclusion follows by squeezing.

**Is it correct?**